# Difference between power of a random variable and product of random variable with itself

Tags: r, random-variable

In the `R` package `distr` there are two infix operators `^` and `*` that can be applied to random variables to generate new random variables. Example `R` code:

```
library(distr)
Norm()^2
Norm() * Norm()
```

However, these two operations do not produce the same thing. Let $X$ be a random variable; in our example $X \sim \operatorname{Norm}(0, 1)$. If I am interpreting the package maintainer correctly, the first is the image $\operatorname{Im}(X)$ of the map $X \to X^2$ and the second is the image of the map $X \times Y \to XY$.

I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between the two definitions above? In particular, is the first equivalent to the transformation $f(x) = x^2$ on the pdf of $X$?
2. Is it usual to use this notation? It's quite confusing that $X^2 \neq X*X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct: The first is simply a univariate *transformation* of the random variable $X$. The second is the product of two *independent* random variables.

In fact, I would go so far as to say that it is incorrect to use the notation $X*X$ for this, since it suggests equivalence with $X^2$. A better notation would be to use $X_i*X_j$.

They are completely different objects.

Comment: So, if I write $X + X$ would you consider this to be the sum of two independent and identically distributed random variables, or would it be more precise to write $X_1 + X_2$ where $X_1, X_2 \sim \operatorname{Norm}(0,1)$.

Comment: @Alex yes, it would be more precise to indicate that they are two separate data points, observations, or draws. The "lazier" notation is still used quite a lot when the context is clear..